# Rails 3.0.3: using vestal_versions with globalize3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, localization, vestal-versions

I am trying to add **vestal_versions** (1.2.2) to a site that uses **globalize3** (0.0.11) for localization of the Models.

When I try to display the Version of a Model like this:

```
 <% if can?(:edit, Page) then %>
  <div class="edit_link"><%= link_to image_tag("appicons/edit.png", :alt => t(:edit)), edit_page_path(@page) %><br />
  Version <%= @page.version %></div>
<% end %>
```

I get:

> **TypeError in Viewer#show**
>
> Showing /home/florian/spzwww3/app/views/viewer/show.html.erb where line #50 raised:
>
> *Cannot visit Condition*

Line #50 being the one with `@page.version`

Displaying the Version in the console works fine:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > p = Page.find(:last)
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > p.version
 => 1
```

Any ideas what "Cannot visit Condition" condition means?

I've never seen that message before, and google returns only one unrelated result for that phrase.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

---

Here is the Full trace:

> arel (2.0.6) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:21:in `rescue in visit'
>   arel (2.0.6) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in`visit'
>   arel (2.0.6) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:109:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_Grouping'
>   arel (2.0.6) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in`visit'
>   arel (2.0.6) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:89:in `block in visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectCore'
>   arel (2.0.6) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:89:in`map'
>   arel (2.0.6) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:89:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectCore'
>   arel (2.0.6) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:77:in`block in visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement'
>   arel (2.0.6) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:77:in `map'
>   arel (2.0.6) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:77:in`visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement'
>   arel (2.0.6) lib/arel/visitors/sqlite.rb:7:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement'
>   arel (2.0.6) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in`visit'
>   arel (2.0.6) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
>   arel (2.0.6) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:19:in`block in accept'
>   activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:110:in `with_connection'
>   arel (2.0.6) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:17:in`accept'
>   arel (2.0.6) lib/arel/tree_manager.rb:19:in `to_sql'
>   activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/relation.rb:318:in`to_sql'
>   activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:207:in `execute_simple_calculation'
>   activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:182:in`perform_calculation'
>   activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:152:in `calculate'
>   activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:84:in`maximum'
>   activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/base.rb:442:in `maximum'
>   activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:443:in`block in method_missing'
>   activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/base.rb:1121:in `with_scope'
>   activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:203:in`with_scope'
>   activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:439:in `method_missing'
>   /home/florian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/vestal_versions-6273df533f85/lib/vestal_versions/reversion.rb:66:in`last_version'
>   /home/florian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/vestal_versions-6273df533f85/lib/vestal_versions/reversion.rb:10:in `version'
>   app/views/viewer/show.html.erb:50:in`_app_views_viewer_show_html_erb___3169340765490706064_17989400_4488323425482422564'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `block in render'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:54:in`instrument'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:127:in `render'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:59:in`block in _render_template'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in`instrument'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:56:in`_render_template'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:114:in`_render_template'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:108:in `render_to_body'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:47:in`render_to_body'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:55:in `render_to_body'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:101:in`render_to_string'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:92:in `render'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:17:in`render'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in`block in ms'
>   /home/florian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:309:in `realtime'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in`ms'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:78:in`cleanup_view_runtime'
>   activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:15:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in`render'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in`send_action'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:450:in`*run*_2100642650872989332__process_action_*2749632540183314212*_callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in`run_callbacks'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`block in process_action'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in`instrument'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:120:in`process'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:40:in `process'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in`dispatch'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in`block in action'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in`dispatch'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
>   rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in`block in call'
>   rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
>   rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:264:in`optimized_each'
>   rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
>   rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:492:in `call'
>   warden (1.0.2) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in`block in call'
>   warden (1.0.2) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
>   warden (1.0.2) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in`call'
>   rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:295:in `call'
>   /home/florian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/rails-ckeditor-49cb3b60b3ed/lib/ckeditor/middleware.rb:15:in`call'
>   activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
>   activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in`cache'
>   activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
>   activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in`call'
>   activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:353:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in`block in call'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_call_callbacks'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in`call'
>   rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:46:in `call'
>   railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in`call'
>   rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in`call'
>   rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
>   <internal:prelude>:10:in`synchronize'
>   rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in`call'
>   railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
>   railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in`method_missing'
>   railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
>   rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in`call'
>   rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
>   /home/florian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in`service'
>   /home/florian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
>   /home/florian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in`block in start_thread'